# How to decrypt an AES encrypted transport stream segment with Golang?

Tags: go, aes

I know using openssl (tested with OpenSSL 1.1.0g), the following stanza works to decrypt [enc.ts](https://s.natalian.org/2018-01-02/enc.ts), mimetype: video/MP2T, to a `ffplay` playable clear.ts h264 segment:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in enc.ts -out clear.ts -iv 353833383634 -K 9e8c69bcaafa6b636e076935e29986b5 -nosalt
```

Though with Golang's https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#NewCBCDecrypter I'm very confused how the hexadecimal key and iv are set as byte slices, whether block sizes are a factor and how to load and write out the file.

I have tried:

```
package main

import (
        "crypto/aes"
        "crypto/cipher"
        "encoding/hex"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
)

func checkerror(err error) {
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
}

func main() {
        key, err := hex.DecodeString("9e8c69bcaafa6b636e076935e29986b5")
        checkerror(err)
        iv, err := hex.DecodeString("353833383634")
        checkerror(err)
        ciphertext, err := ioutil.ReadFile("enc.ts")
        checkerror(err)
        block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
        checkerror(err)
        mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)
        mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext, ciphertext)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", ciphertext)
}
```

But that results in a `panic: cipher.NewCBCDecrypter: IV length must equal block size`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `iv` is indeed too short so the openssl just padded zero for you:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in enc.ts -out clear.ts -iv 353833383634 -K 9e8c69bcaafa6b636e076935e29986b5 -nosalt -P
key=9E8C69BCAAFA6B636E076935E29986B5
iv =35383338363400000000000000000000
```

Comment: Ah that works! Now to figure out how to pad in Golang.

Comment: A hint: the encoded IV should be 32-digit long while decoded should be 16 bytes.